# How to get compiler to prefer const method overloading in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, c++17, lazy-initialization, perfect-forwarding

I've got a C++ member function of a class with a `const` and non-`const` overloading.

```
Class Example {
public:
  int const & Access() const;
  int       & Access();

  [...]
};
```

I wish for the const version to be preferred as the performance is way superior in my code, the non-const version causing a copy of the underlying shared object to be created to permit modification.

Right now, if my caller has a non-const `Example` object, the non-const Access() method is used even if the resultant int is not modified.

```
Example example;

if ( modify ) {
    example.Access() = 23;    // Need to perform expensive copy here.
} else {
    cout << example.Access(); // No need to copy, read-only access.
}
```

Is there a way, such as distinguishing lvalue and rvalue uses of the return value, perhaps using perfect forwarding with templates, to create a similar mechanism in C++17 that permits the caller to have one syntax which the compiler only uses the non-const version if the return value is modified?

Another example of where I need this is `operator -> ()` where I have a `const` and non-`const` version of the operator.  When calling a method that is `const` I'd like the compiler to prefer the `const` version of `operator -> ()`.

```
Class Shared {
  public:
    int Read() const;
    void Write(int value);

    [...]
};

template <typename BaseClass>
class Callback {
public:
  BaseClass const * operator -> () const; // No tracking needed, read-only access.
  BaseClass       * operator -> ();       // Track possible modification.

  [...]
};

typedef Callback<Shared> SharedHandle;

Shared shared;
SharedHandle sharedHandle(&shared);

if ( modify ) {
  sharedHandle->write(23);
} else {
  cout << sharedHandle->Read();
}
```

Comment: A good solution would be to use differently-named functions for the two cases. `std::string` takes this route, it was originally designed to support copy-on-write semantics. `operator[](n)` makes the copy whereas `c_str()[n]` does not.

Comment: Another option is to have the function return a proxy object that overloads operators in various ways (e.g. in the Access case the return value might overload `operator=` to perform the copy)

Comment: If the non-const version returns a copy, why return it by reference ?

Comment: @SidS It could be `int Access() const;` but more generally, if something complex is in play here, other than POD, then returning a reference could be better.

Comment: Maybe you want **Copy-on-write** which might be tricky to get it right. As many have proposed, the proxy solution would works.

Comment: `std::as_const` could be used at callside

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to make a `CAccess` member (Like `cbegin` on stdlib containers):

```cpp
class Example {
public:
  int const & Access() const;
  int       & Access();
  int const & CAccess() const { return Access(); }
  // No non-const CAccess, so always calls `int const& Access() const`
};
```

This has the downside that you need to remember to call `CAccess` if you don't modify it.

You could also return a proxy instead:

```cpp
class Example;

class AccessProxy {
  Example& e;
  explicit AccessProxy(Example& e_) noexcept : e(e_) {}
  friend class Example;
public:
  operator int const&() const;
  int& operator=(int) const;
};

class Example {
public:
  int const & Access() const;
  AccessProxy Access() {
      return { *this };
  }
private:
  int & ActuallyAccess();
  friend class AccessProxy;
};

inline AccessProxy::operator int const&() const {
    return e.Access();
}

inline int& AccessProxy::operator=(int v) const {
    int& value = e.ActuallyAccess();
    value = v;
    return value;
};
```

But the downside here is that the type is no longer `int&`, which might lead to some issues, and only `operator=` is overloaded.

The second one can easily apply to `operator`s, by making a template class, something like this:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template<class T, class Class, T&(Class::* GetMutable)(), T const&(Class::* GetImmutable)() const>
class AccessProxy {
  Class& e;
  T& getMutable() const {
      return (e.*GetMutable)();
  }
  const T& getImmutable() const {
      return (e.*GetImmutable)();
  }
public:
  explicit AccessProxy(Class& e_) noexcept : e(e_) {}
  operator T const&() const {
      return getImmutable();
  }
  template<class U>
  decltype(auto) operator=(U&& arg) const {
      return (getMutable() = std::forward<U>(arg));
  }
};

class Example {
public:
  int const & Access() const;
  auto Access() {
      return AccessProxy<int, Example, &Example::ActuallyAccess, &Example::Access>{ *this };
  }
private:
  int & ActuallyAccess();
};
```

(Though `AccessProxy::operator->` would need to be defined too)

and the first method just doesn't work with `operator` members (Unless you're willing to change `sharedHandle->read()` into `sharedHandle.CGet().read()`)

Answer (score 3):

You could have the non-const version return a proxy object which determines whether a modification is needed based on its usage.

```
class Example {
private:
    class AccessProxy {
        friend Example;
    public:
        AccessProxy(AccessProxy const &) = delete;

        operator int const & () const &&
        { return std::as_const(*m_example).Access(); }

        operator int const & operator= (int value) && {
            m_example->assign(value);
            return *this;
        }

        operator int const & operator= (AccessProxy const & rhs) && {
            m_example->assign(rhs);
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        explicit AccessProxy(Example & example) : m_example(&example) {}
        Example * const m_example;
    };

public:
  int const & Access() const;
  AccessProxy Access() { return AccessProxy(*this); }

  // ...

private:
  void assign(int value);
};
```

This doesn't allow modifying operators directly on the proxy like `++example.Access()` or `example.Access *= 3`, but those could be added as well.

Note this isn't entirely equivalent to the original. Obviously, you can't bind an `int&` reference to an `example.Access()` expression. And there could be differences where code that worked before involving a user-defined conversion now fails to compile since it would require two user-defined conversions. The trickiest difference is that in code like

```
auto && thing = example.Access();
```

the type of `thing` is now the hidden type `Example::AccessProxy`. You can document not to do that, but passing it via perfect forwarding to function templates could get into some dangerous or unexpected behavior. Deleting the copy constructor and making the other public members require an rvalue is an attempt to stop most accidental incorrect uses of the proxy type, but it's not entirely perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a 100% match for the question, but instead of modifying many classes that have this issue, you could create a convenience template function:

```
template <typename T>
inline T const& cnst(T& a)
{
    return a;
}
```

This can then be used as such:

```
Example example;

if ( modify ) {
    example.Access() = 23;    // Need to perform expensive copy here.
} else {
    cout << cnst(example).Access(); // No need to copy, read-only access.
}
```

The nice thing about this is that you have full control over when to explicitly use only const access, but if for some reason your object is already const, it will also still work (as a const const& is still a const&).

The downside is of course that you need put this in your code manually, while you would want the compiler to detect it.

This is of course essentially a const_cast, but it's much nicer to use.

Comment: Rather than defining this, use `std::as_const`.